# How to apply a JavaFX transform to a rotation/attitude axis/angle?

Tags: javafx

There is a Transform#transform(X,Y,Z) method that I am able to use like this:

```
Transform t = node.getLocalToSceneTransform();
Point3D xyz = t.transform(node.getTranslateX(),node.getTranslateY(),node.getTranslateZ());
```

How do I do the companion transform of an attitude (axis/angle), something like:

```
double angle = node.getRotate();
Point3D axis = node.getRotationAxis();
t.transform(angle, axis) // ??
```

I do not see methods in either Transform or Affine class to do this.

Here is the closest related post: [How to get the absolute rotation of a Node in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741574/how-to-get-the-absolute-rotation-of-a-node-in-javafx)